# using the testcase name in output file names

Tags: c++, boost-test

I use `boost::test` to run integration tests on a class that creates directories and files. I would like
these files to be named test-case specific so if I run into trouble I can easily find which test case left its directories/files around.

So I would like to use the test case name in the constructor of the fixture that I'm using, as demonstrated below. Is this possible at all, and how? I searched the boost::test manual but could not find this information.

e.g.

```
struct foo_fixture
{
    foo_fixture() 
    { 
        std::string case_dependent_name( BOOST_TEST_CASE_NAME ); 
        create_directory( case_dependent_name );
    }
};

BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE ( foo_case_one, foo_fixture )
{
   ...
}
BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE ( foo_case_two, foo_fixture )
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this, and it works:

[boost user group discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/boost-list/browse_thread/thread/673166bb5e147de4?pli=1)

Essentially, you use the string member variable found on the test_unit instance:

```
boost::unit_test::framework::current_test_case().p_name
```